# Is there any way to update the application/webpage after changes are made to the HTML/CSS file in Flask? (Without debug mode)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, flask, hot-reload

I'm working on a web application and I noticed something annoying that happens. Whenever I make a change to the project templates I have to go to the browser and refresh the page to see the changes. I would like to know if there is any function that does this automatically, like in VS Code's Live Server extension.

I've already read some tutorials to activate debug mode, but this is already activated and from what I understand, only changes made to the application's main file are updated: main.py

I want to know if there is any configuration or extension to update the application page whenever a change is made to the application templates, be it a change in the html or css file.

Comment: Saves to any static files or templates would always be seen on a refresh. An extension isn't necessary. You can change the launch configuration arguments to run in debug mode